# Unable to read Azure Eventhub topics from spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

Enviroment details

1. spark version : 3.x
2. Python version 3.8 and java version 8
3. azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12-2.3.17.jar

```
import json
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


#the below command getOrCreate() uses the SparkSession shared across the jobs instead of using one SparkSession per job.
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('ntorq_eventhub_load').getOrCreate()

#ntorq adls checkpoint location.
ntorq_connection_string = "connection-string"

ehConf = {}
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(ntorq_connection_string)
# ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = ntorq_connection_string
ehConf['eventhubs.consumerGroup'] = "$default"

OFFSET_START = "-1"   # the beginning
OFFSET_END = "@latest"

# Create the positions
startingEventPosition = {
  "offset": OFFSET_START ,
  "seqNo": -1,            #not in use
  "enqueuedTime": None,   #not in use
  "isInclusive": True
}

endingEventPosition = {
  "offset": OFFSET_END,           #not in use
  "seqNo": -1,              #not in use
  "enqueuedTime": None,
  "isInclusive": True
}

# Put the positions into the Event Hub config dictionary
ehConf["eventhubs.startingPosition"] = json.dumps(startingEventPosition)
ehConf["eventhubs.endingPosition"] = json.dumps(endingEventPosition)


df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .load() \
  .selectExpr("cast(body as string) as body_str")

df.writeStream \
    .format("console") \
    .start()
```

error

```
21/04/25 20:17:53 WARN Utils: Your hostname,resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.168.1.202 instead (on interface en0)
21/04/25 20:17:53 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
21/04/25 20:17:53 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(ntorq_connection_string)
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

Code is working fine on databricks environment but unable to consume all messages from eventhub I tried clearing the default checkpointing folders before running every time but still facing the issue, so want to try on the local system.
When trying on local environment facing JavaPackage issue.
Appreciate any help.
thank you

Comment: How do you run it in the local environment

Comment: I trying to consume the Azure Eventhub topic from my local environment.
I am running the spark code in pycharm Ide.

Comment: but to consume it you need to have EventHubs library, etc.  How have you added it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add EventHubs package when creating session:

```py
park = SparkSession.builder.appName('eventhub_load')\
  .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.18")\
  .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Hi Alex,
thank you for your comment.
I have manually added the azure-eventhub jar to spark class path.
Please feel free to comment further.

Comment: that's really strange - the code for encrypt is correct one.

Comment: Hi,
I found out the solution. I tried by setting all the spark Env Variables then it worked like a charm.

Comment: what specific environment variables have you used?

Comment: SPARK_HOME, PYSPARK_PYTHON, PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON environment variables were set in the pycharm then it worked like a charm.